# how to trigger a chrome.tabs onClick event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, onclick

Is there any way to fire or simulate a click event on the currently-open Chrome tab using the `chrome.tabs` API?

Looking through [chrome.tabs extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), I'm finding events such as `onHighlighted` and `onActivated`, but they seem to deal with changing the current tab and/or window.

I'm looking for a way to respond to clicking the current tab, such as using the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.onClicked.addListener(function (tabId, tab) { 
    alert("Clicked!");    
});
```

But sadly, this doesn't work. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Clicking on the current tab doesn't do anything. It doesn't even change focus. Is there a reason you expect users would ever click on the current tab?

Comment: @sowbug In most circumstances, no, but I'm experimenting with some functionality that involves clicking the current tab. This is mostly out of curiosity though since I didn't see anything in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Clicking on the current tab doesn't do anything, and users wouldn't normally click there for any reason (unless of course they're about to click the X to close), so it wouldn't make sense to generate an event for that click. Doing so would give potential meaning to an unclickable part of the browser chrome, which would be really confusing for users.

Comment: What if I want to add a handler to that event so that clicking on the current tab actually does something? I'd like to write an extension that scrolls to the top of the page when the user clicks on the currently active tab.

Comment: Hey @tinkerr did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Visionwriter I did not. I worked around it by writing a Javascript bookmarklet. It's not ideal because it takes up space in the bookmarks bar.